# pass emit click to parent in slot element to run function in parent vue 3 slot option api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

greeting king,

I'm trying to emit click from child(todoitem.vue) element that contains button and slot in this component to parent(app.vue) that will run a method in parent. For example now when I click edit button then method in parent editable() will run and when I click delete button then run method of deletable() in parent. How to approach this. I had tried to pass using v-slot but it only send variable also try emit but failed to emit. I'm totally new to vue..thanks

parent(app.vue)

```
<template>
<div>
  <todolist>
      <todoitem v-for="each in a" :key="each.list">
          {{each.list}}
      </todoitem>

  </todolist>
    <todolist>
      <todoitem v-for="each in b" :key="each.list">
          {{each.list}}
      </todoitem>

  </todolist>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import todolist from "./components/todolist.vue";
import todoitem from "./components/todoitem.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    return{
      a:[
        {list:"AAAA"},
          {list:"BBBB"},
            {list:"CCC"},
      ],
            b:[
        {list:"DDDD"},
          {list:"EEEE"},
            {list:"FFFF"},
      ],

    }
  },
  components: {
 
    todolist,
    todoitem
  },
  methods:{
    editable(){
      console.log('editabel')
      
    },
    deletable(){
      console.log('deletable')
      
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

child(todoitem)

```
<template>
<slot></slot>

    <button @click="test">Edit</button>
   <button @click="test2">delete</button>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "todoitem",
method:{
  test(){
    console.log('edit click')
    this.$emit('edit-item')
  },
    test2(){
    console.log('delete click')
    this.$emit('del-item')
  }
}


}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

todolist

```
<template>
<slot></slot>
  <div>
   
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "todolist",

};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's structured like this - just put an `emit` with the `function-name` and the paramters inside of one of your `methods` like this:

*Child.vue*

```
this.$emit("Your_Function_Name", Parameter_1, Parameter_2);
```

Than go to your `parent.vue` call your emitted function and use it inside your `methods` of the `parent.vue`:

*Parent.vue*

```
<template>
  ...
  <Child @Your_Function_Name="Your_Function_Name">
  ...
</template>
```

```
<script>
  methods: {
    Your_Function_Name(Parameter_1, Parameter_2) {
      console.log(Parameter_1, Parameter_2)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: should i pass to @Your_Function_Name="Your_Function_Name" at slot at todolist first or direct put at parent where there is todoitem? I have tried put on app.vue but it doesn't worked

Comment: You have to put it there where you want to use it! :)

Comment: here the codesandbox..i put it in parent app-vue and click it become error [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slot-vue-vijl0?file=/src/App.vue)